# How to open a URL in chrome via terminal in windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, terminal

I want to open a specific URL in chrome via terminal in windows. I can open chrome via terminal by going to the directory where chrome is installed and calling `chrome.exe` in the terminal. And it opens a new window in Chrome.

But, how to open a URL in chrome through terminal, via some passed arguments in terminal??

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/731467/command-line-option-to-open-chrome-in-new-window-and-move-focus)

Comment: Yes this is the one. Thanks!!